# Add DropDownList selected item to a list dynamically in .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a DropDownList in my razor view, it is getting the values from my model which is populated from Data Base. What I want to achieve is when selecting an option from that DropDownList and clicking a button, show a list of this options selected one below the other, all in the same view and next to every item a link for edit or delete. Then in another screen I can add this final "list" to my data base. This is part of my code:

Model

```
public class SchedulerViewModel
{        
        public string Frequency { get; set; }     
        public string SelectedReportValue { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ReportList
        {
            get
            {
                List<string> reportlist = DataAccess.retrieveReportList();
                return new SelectList(reportlist);
            }
        }

        public string NewCronName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "OrderDate")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FrequencyList
        {
            get
            {
                List<string> frequencyList = DataAccess.retrieveFrequencyList();
                return new SelectList(frequencyList);
            }
        }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddCron()
{                  
    return View();            
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddCron(SchedulerViewModel model)
{            
    return View(model);
}
```

View

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        $("#div1").load('@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedReportValue)');

    }
</script>
.
.
.


<tr>
    <td><h5>Frequency: </h5></td>
    <td> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Frequency, Model.FrequencyList)</td>

    <td><h5>First Run Date: </h5></td>        
    <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", @id = "datepicker" })</td>        
</tr>
<tr class="blank_row">
                &nbsp;
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><p><b>Add Report</b></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><h5>Report :</h5></td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedReportValue, Model.ReportList)</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Add" value="Add" onclick="myFunction()" /></td>
</tr>

<div id="div1"></div>
```

I can see the returning selected value in my model in the [HttpPost] method, but still can't make it work in the view. Any suggestion?

[image]

and this is what I'm trying to get...

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using a partial view for this?

Comment: @nocturns2 not really familiar on how to solve it with partial view, can you point me to an example so I can understand it better?

Comment: Please remove the unnecessary codes. They are really confusing.

Comment: I didn't have any example in mind originally, but I did a search for ( example of displaying a partial view by selecting an option from a dropdown list ) and found these sample links. Simple fundamental example: http://www.aspdotnet-pools.com/2014/07/aspnet-mvc-partial-view-display-on.html and More complex examples that uses jQuery and ajax: https://chsakell.com/2013/09/25/master-detail-dropdown-lists-and-partial-views-with-jquery-ajax-in-mvc/ and http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2011/06/filter-and-display-data-with-aspnet-mvc-part-2partial-views-and-jquery.html

Comment: The basic idea is that you can have more flexibility over the content you display when you make a selection from your dropdown such as showing tabular data and having links as well as other routing controls. The partial views can be hidden or displayed on your main page. With ajax, you can make it seem seamless.

Comment: Impossible to understand your requirement from the limited description. From the 2nd image, best guess is that you select a report, then select a file type, then click 'Add' to add the selected values to the 'Selected Reports' list (and you can keep repeating that workflow to add more Report/FileType pairs? And neither of your images appear to relate to the model you have shown

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think the images explain well what I want. The first one is my code, and I shared the second one so I can show somehow what I want. I just need to add Report to a list and show it in the same view. Supposedly in the next screen I add one more option and when done I save it to the data base . Obviously, if is there any report added previously it show them as well. The model corresponds to the first image

Comment: Sorry, but its not clear at all. The first image has controls for Cron Name, Frequency and a Date but the model does not relate to that at all. The model does contain `List<string>` properties for `AddedReportNames` and `AddedSelectedReportNames` which don't seem to relate to anything in your images. Its not even clear if thats the `SchedulerViewModel` you refer to in the controller.

Comment: I made a best guess in my previous comment but you have not even confirmed if that's correct or not. And there is no point adding extra info in comments (we don't answer comments). You need to edit the question to explain what your trying to do.

Comment: @StephenMuecke you are right, since the code was kinda long, I put what I thought was more relevant, but we got confused, I apologize. I updated the info in my question to reflect better my concern. About the second pic is just to show the list that is created once I click add.

Comment: Its unclear why you want 2 views for this. And forcing the user to add items by continuously scrolling through and selecting items from dropdownlists is not a good UI. Not sure if I have interpreted your requirements correctly, but suggest you look at [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BWbyR6) as a starting point.

Comment: And as a side note, never put database access code in your view model. Not only have you made it impossible to unit test, when you submit the form, you making unnecessary database calls to populate the SelectLists (the only time they are needed in the POST method is if `ModelState` is invalid and you need to return the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke the reason I was using a dropdownlist is because there are many records for that dropdownlist, so instead of having the user scroll down the page to visualize all of them, I prefer to have them use a drop down list. However, your example is really useful . Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try get rid of jquery, just use razor :

```
<div id="div1">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedReportValue)
</div>
```

Base of your comment I suggest you can use jquery to trigger change event and add item to the list manually :

```
$( "#filetype" ).change(function() {
  //code handler to add to list
});
```

Comment: but I need to add new elements everytime I select an item from the DropDownList and click on the button. So I don't think this is going to work